# Python Pandas: how to change between selection by label and selection by index

Tags: python, pandas

I know we have the method `loc[]` for selection by label and `iloc[]` for selection by index. But I am struggling when I want to change from one to other or even mix them.

Let's say we have data of animals and its stats:

```
import pandas as pd
csv = [
    ['cat', 5, 2, 9],
    ['dog', 7, 8, 6],
    ['fish', 3, 1, 4]
]
df = pd.DataFrame(csv, columns=['animal', 'speed', 'strength', 'agility'])
df = df.set_index('animal')
```

And now I want to know the dog's strength. I run:

```
df.loc['dog','strength']
```

and I get the desired output. But what if now I want to know which indexes are associated to this output?

And the oposite situation. Let's say I know the indexes and I run:

```
df.iloc[1][1]
```

but now I want to know which animal and which stat is associated with this result.

In other words, how to know that 'dog' is row = 1 and that 'strength' is column = 1 and viceversa?

Moreover, what if I want to combine labels and indexes. In my example it will something like "get the second column for dog's row". How can I do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Look up `get_loc`.  For your question, it would be `df.iloc[df.index.get_loc('dog'), 1]`.  `get_loc` can be called on any index, so it will work for the index, as well as the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can using `get_indexer`

```
i, j = df.index.get_indexer(['dog']),df.columns.get_indexer(['strength'])
i
Out[522]: array([1], dtype=int64)
j
Out[523]: array([1], dtype=int64)

df.iloc[i,j]
Out[528]: 
        strength
animal          
dog            8
```

Comment: Nice! But I don't get why `get_indexer` returns an array. If I try to use it on a dataframe with many repetead indexes it throws an error "Reindexing only valid with uniquely" " valued Index objects" so what's the point in returning an array?

Answer (score 1):

If you added you indexes/column headers in brackets, you will return a dataframe instead of the scalar value.   For example:

```
df.loc[['dog'],['strength']]
```

Output:

```
        strength
animal          
dog            8
```

OR,

```
df.iloc[[1],[1]]
```

Output:

```
        strength
animal          
dog            8
```

Comment: Understood. And is there any diference between `df.iloc[2][2]` and `df.iloc[2,2]` ? Is hard to me to remember the 3 different forms, I don't see the logic behind...

Comment: df.iloc[2][2] is a no-no in pandas.  This is called chained indexing.  This may lead to unintended consequences.  The proper way to access this cell in a dataframe is to use df.iloc[2,2].